# Can I validate the presence of one of three options in multiple select lists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

[link to sample page with test form](http://i-cre8.com/test-files/jquery-validation/index.php)

I have a situation where I am importing a spreadsheet and I need to map some or all of the columns in the spreadsheet to fields in my database but I want to ensure that at least one select list has one of three price options selected, which are Regular Price, Sell Price or Promo Price. The other select lists can have the Brand or Model options selected or even be blank but at least one select list must have one of the price options selected.

Is there a way to do this with the jQuery Validation Plugin that I have not been able to find in my google searches ?

```
<form action="" id="frmTest" method="post" name="frmTest">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><select name="MapTo_A" id="MapTo_A">
          <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
          <option value="SKU">Model</option>
          <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
          <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
          <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="MapTo_B" id="MapTo_B">
          <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
          <option value="SKU">Model</option>
          <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
          <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
          <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="MapTo_C" id="MapTo_C">
          <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
          <option value="SKU">Model</option>
          <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
          <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
          <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
        </select></td>
  <td><select name="MapTo_D" id="MapTo_D">
      <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
      <option value="SKU">Model</option>
      <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
      <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
      <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
    </select></td>
  <td><select name="MapTo_E" id="MapTo_E">
      <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
      <option value="SKU">Model</option>
      <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
      <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
      <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
    </select></td>
  <td><select name="MapTo_F" id="MapTo_F">
      <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;----&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <option value="CommonBrandName">Brand</option>
      <option value="SKU">Model</option>
      <option value="MSRP">Regular Price</option>
      <option value="Price">Sell Price</option>
      <option value="Sale">Promo Price</option>
    </select></td>
        ...
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><input type="submit" id="updateNow" name="updateNow" value="Map Columns"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the complexity you describe, you'll need to write your own custom rule using [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  Simply `return` `true` to say the field has "passed" validation and `false` to "fail" validation.

Example with optional params:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customRule", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == params[0] + params[1];
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}"));


$('#yourform').validate({
    rules: {
        MapTo_A: {
            customRule: [param1, param2, etc],
            // customRule: true // without parameters
        }
        ....
```

Note:  The `this.optional(element) ||` part ensures that this rule will not also force the `required` rule.  For a situation where you also want the field to be `required`, declare the `required` rule separately.

---

However, for the best user experience, you should use JavaScript to dynamically rewrite your other `select` elements' options based on the `change` events of the other `select` elements.  Ideally, you wouldn't want to show a user any options he's not allowed to select in the first place.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will read the docs you linked to and see what I can do. If you look at my example page you will see that when an option is selected it is removed from the other select lists